# Email Regular expression allowing invalid appended character at the end

Tags: regex, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

I have a regular expression for validating email addresses. It works pretty well, but it doesn't pick up if I've added any characters at the end. For example, if I try.... "eee" it will flag it as invalid, If I try "ddd@dddd.com" that passes, but if I try "dfdfd@Dfdf.comd" it also passes. Is there anything to stop these invalid characters being picked up at the end?

Here is my regex:

```
^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$
```

Thanks

Comment: This question has been asked an enormous number of times on SO - please use the search function, e.g. [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 1):

You can check for common endings with a list such as `(com|uk|org|gov)` but there are [so many variations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) that checking them all isn't suited to regex. Either you pull out the top-level domain and check it against a list, or you trust your users.

Comment: There are going to be a lot more variations soon, as ICANN is allowing people to create their own [top-level domains](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/) :)

Comment: Yeah, like I said, this isn't really suited to regex.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your pattern would have to know about all valid suffixes.

A regex for validating standard compliant eMail addresses is in fact quite complex. Check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for some pointers on how to achieve this.

"Short" answer (taken from the above link, didn't test it, you might have to adapt it to your regex implementation):

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b
```

As you can see, that pattern also does some sort of whitelisting for the valid suffixes.

**EDIT:**
Or just check out this answer, good explanation and a reference to the official standard regex (it seems): [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)